# Kotlin Android Studio - Var is seen as val in SDK 29

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm experiencing a pretty strange thing in Kotlin.
I have

```
var myClipboard = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager?
var myClip: ClipData? = ClipData.newPlainText( /* my code */ )
```

As a `var` variable, I should be able to reassign his value, but when I do

```
myClipboard?.primaryClip = myClip
```

It gives me the error

> Val cannot be reassigned

The strangest things is that I'm using this code by weeks and it always worked. It stopped working today when I updated to API 29

This is my `build.gradle` `android{}`

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.arfmann.pushnotes"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 16
        versionName "1.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `myClip` is a `var`, `myClipboard` is a `var`. You are trying to set `myClipboard?.primaryClip`, which is neither of those. Still, your syntax should work. Try switching it to `myClipboard?.setPrimaryClip()` and see what you get.

Comment: The error is referring to `primaryClip` and not `myClipboard`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As seen in the [`ClipboardManager` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/ClipboardManager.html), `getPrimaryClip` returns a `ClipData?` (i.e., a nullable `ClipData`) while `setPrimaryClip()` takes a `ClipData` - a non-null `ClipData`.

Kotlin does not support `var` property access when the types are different (and nullability is an important part of Kotlin typing) therefore Kotlin can only give you effectively the `val` equivalent when you call `primaryClip`.

The nullability annotation on `setPrimaryClip` was added in API 29, which is why the behavior is different once you upgrade your `compileSdkVersion`.

To set the primary clip, you must explicitly use `setPrimaryClip()` with a non-null `ClipData` or, on API 28+, use [`clearPrimaryClip()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/ClipboardManager.html#clearPrimaryClip()) to completely clear the primary clip.

Comment: hi @ianhannibalake, I have tried but still not working will you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359729/val-can-not-be-reassigned-at-clipboardmanager-primaryclip

Comment: This helped a lot! Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Use it like this

```
val clipboard = ctx.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
val clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Beacon infos", it.toJson())
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working copy,

```
    val myClipboard = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager?
    val myClip: ClipData? = ClipData.newPlainText("", "")

    myClipboard?.primaryClip = myClip
```

Hope this can help you