# Val can not be reassigned at ClipboardManager primaryClip

Tags: android, kotlin, clipboardmanager

I know this [question is already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57128725/kotlin-android-studio-var-is-seen-as-val-in-sdk-29) but still, it does not help me to resolve issue

I am getting issue while copy data to clipboard-manager

below is code

```
fun copyToClipboard(context: Context, text: CharSequence){
        var clipboard: ClipboardManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
        var clip: ClipData = ClipData.newPlainText("label",text)
        clipboard.primaryClip = clip!!
    }
```

as @ianhanniballake suggested, I have already use use setPrimaryClip() with a non-null ClipData

like below

```
var clip: ClipData = ClipData.newPlainText("label",text)
clipboard.primaryClip = clip!!
```

But don't know why, still I am getting same error like

```
Val cannot be reassigned
```

Comment: In your "like bellow" you didn't use `setPrimaryClip()`. Please fix your examples.

Comment: Also don't use `!!` it will throw NPE. You can use it If you like shooting yourself in the foot ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must use method `setPrimaryClip()`, for example:

```
clipboard?.setPrimaryClip(clip)
```

because field `primaryClip` has only getter.

Comment: The API updated when I forced my app to minimum SDK of 29.  This helped me fix the issue.